# What does () mean at the end of Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl

```
sub f {
    # some code here
    () 
}
```

What does () mean in this Perl subroutine?

Comment: Return empty list.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_subroutines.htm - see the section on Return values.

Comment: The potential confusion is why it's usually a good idea to include an explicit `return` statement in subroutines longer than one line.

Comment: It depends significantly on `some code here`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The last expression in a sub will be the return value. This ensures that (assuming no previous `return` statements) the sub returns an empty list (rather then whatever was on the previous line of code).

Answer (score 1):

OK ... so it is perhaps pathological, but this **IS** Perl we're talking about...

Depending on the actual text of "# some code here", it could conceivably produce a dereferenced CODE reference, in which case the parens would cause the CODE to be invoked with zero arguments, and the return value of that code would be the return value of `f'.

For example, the following will print out a single lowercase "a":

```
    sub f {
        &{sub { return $_[0] }}
       (@_)
    }

    print f(qw( a b c d e f )), "\n";
```

Comment: I like it.  That was actually the first thing I thought of too. =)

Comment: Not pathological at all.  It could easily be this or a different way of spelling `return;`.  Can't know without context.